# Change an editable-text value in Allegro CL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos, allegro-cl

I'm trying to change the value of an Editable-Text control in Allegro CL (version 8.0.1) by clicking a Default-Button.

I've read about `(setf value)` but haven't found any examples.

The function I have ttached to the on-click event is the following

```
    (defun form1-default-button-2-on-click (dialog widget)
       (declare (ignorable dialog widget))

    t)
```

As you can see there's a lack of code in there :) I've tried various methods as `(setf (slot value :txt 'value) 'TEXT)` and `(setf value 'TEXT)` but to no avail.

The dialog-items slot on the form is a list with the following elements defined by

```
(list (make-instance 'default-button :font
                   (make-font-ex nil "Segoe UI / Default" 12) :left
                   56 :name :default-button-2 :on-change
                   'form1-default-button-2-on-change :top 36)
    (make-instance 'editable-text :font
                   (make-font-ex nil "Segoe UI / Default" 12) :left
                   52 :name :txt :top 152 :value "")
 )
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(setf (slot-value widget 'value) "foo")
```

Something like the above. You need get the symbol  value  in the correct package. probably there is also an accessor function like WIDGET-VALUE .  Then (setf (widget-value widget) "foo")  might work...

I'm not an ACL user - there are probably better ways. ACL specific questions are best asked on their users mailing list.

Comment: The solution with 'slot-value' doesn't work nor does the one with widget-value.

Comment: It was a hint, but you really should use the mailing list for ACL. http://www.franz.com/support/acl.forum.lhtml

Answer (score 0):

There is an example somewhere on franz.com where I found this:

```
(defun form1-button5-on-change (widget new-value old-value)
  (declare (ignorable widget new-value old-value))
  (let ((szerkeszto (find-sibling :multi-line-editable-text-1 widget)))
    (setf (value szerkeszto) "bla" ))
  t) ; Accept the new value
```

symbol "szerkeszto" becomes the multi-line-editable-text-1, then you can use setf like the above to set appropriate attributes (like "value").

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the functions "find-component" and "value" together.

The function "find-component" finds the widget in your project 
                  and "value" returns the value of the widget.

If you have static-text in a form, you can change the value of the static-text like this.

(let ((ed1 (find-component :static-text-1 :form1)))
   (setf (value ed1) "I made it."))